# How to prune Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I wouldn't use most of the classes from Zend Framework, that's why I'm looking for the thinnest possible ZF configuration.

Is there a better way of finding what I really need other than deleting the whole library/Zend folder, then putting back files based on the error messages that I receive?

Comment: I suggest that you do not anything to the Zend Framework core files. Although the files are there, you do not have to load/use every single file. Maintainability wise, it would be a nightmare when you want to upgrade. Just keep the files as it is and load the components you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it myself, but http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/01/zend-framework-automatic-dependency-tracking/ may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think anyone who knows Zend Framework would need this. It just creates overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Hm...

1. There is a lot of information about Zend Framework on SO and with a little bit of reading you would have found the answers to your question
2. You would also find the answers to your question by just reading the introduction to Zend Framework on the Zend Framework website.
3. No, that's not how you'll do it. Zend Framework, unlike most/all other PHP frameworks, is rigidly loosely coupled. You can use every component stand-alone. You can only use the loader, or only Zend_Translate. Or you can just use the MVC modules, or Zend_Db, etc.

Of course if you use Zend_Form and want to validate or filter the input, you'll need Zend_Validate and Zend_Filter. But you'll know that because you'll instantiate objects. So just copy into your empty library folder the modules you need. Or even better, copy everything in! A) you won't regret it. B) disk space is not your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is set up the plugin loader cache and then purge all files apart from the ones called within the automatically generated include file.

[zend.loader.pluginloader.performance](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.pluginloader.html#zend.loader.pluginloader.performance)

I hope it makes sense... :o)